# Parameter fails to list all possible values

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, cascading

My Crystal Report uses a single command to create a cascading parameter for `warehouse.code` :

```
SELECT BILLLINES.RECDATE, ARTICLES.NAME ARTNAME, BILLLINES.QUANTITY QTY,
    ARTICLES.QTSTOCK,WAREHOUSE.NAME WHNAME,DOCTYPE.AKEY, 
    WAREHOUSE.CODE,DOCTYPE.DESCRIPTION
FROM BILLLINES
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ARTICLES  ON ARTICLES.RECID=BILLLINES.ARTICLEID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN WAREHOUSE ON WAREHOUSE.CODE=ARTICLES.WAREHOUSE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DOCHEAD ON BILLLINES.DOCUMENTID=DOCHEAD.RECID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DOCTYPE ON DOCHEAD.DOC_TYPE=DOCTYPE.AKEY
WHERE (WAREHOUSE.CODE='TER' OR WAREHOUSE.CODE='TFW' OR
    WAREHOUSE.CODE='TMS' OR WAREHOUSE.CODE='TNT' OR
    WAREHOUSE.CODE='TSA')
group by WAREHOUSE.CODE, WAREHOUSE.NAME, ARTICLES.NAME,
    BILLLINES.QUANTITY,BILLLINES.RECDATE, 
    ARTICLES.QTSTOCK,DOCTYPE.AKEY,DOCTYPE.DESCRIPTION
```

The database has about 105,000 records for this query. I suspect the command is too large to allow all warehouses to be listed for the cascading parameter.  I tried reducing the number of `warehouse.codes` in the query and that seems to work.

But is there anything I can do to get all the codes I need into the parameter list?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this issue occurs when the LOV exceeds the value set in registry.. We can change the registry to show more values but as you say you have approx 105,000 data, I am not sure whether you will be able to get those many records.

You can get many links when you google.. pasting few links here that may help you.

https://scn.sap.com/thread/977521

http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=8029

[Crystal Reports parameter selection limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568405/crystal-reports-parameter-selection-limit)

Note:I am not pasting the answers from those links so that we can save answers if those links are lost in future.

Try above links and let me know which one is working.. I will add that in the answer.

**Be aware while manipulating the registry values**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13904373)

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 I agree and if you see answer I clearly mentioned once user uses the particular link and informs me I will add it as answer and will remove links